# Best way of (Y/N)

Tags: c, menu, do-while, ncurses

I write this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>
void salir (void);
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char h;
    initscr();
    start_color();
    init_pair(1,COLOR_BLACK,COLOR_BLUE); 
    init_pair(3,COLOR_BLACK,COLOR_WHITE);  
    bkgd(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(3));
    move(2,1);
    printw("Welcome to my first ncurses program :D \n");
    move(3,1);
    printw("Would you like to read the manual? (Y/N)\n");
    do{
        h = getch();
        if(h == 'y' || h == 'Y'){
            printw("1- You must enter the numbers of rows and columns you want\n2- Then you have to specificate the type of data to enter\n");  
            break;
        }

        else if (!(h == 'n' || h == 'N')){ 
            printw("Enter a valid option\n");
        }
    } while (!(h == 'n' || h=='N'));

    printw("hola");
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(3));
    refresh();
    getch();
    salir();

}

void salir(){
    endwin();
    exit(0);
}
```

My doubt is about the Y/N menu. What is the best way to do this? Also, I don't want to show the entered character in the window. It's ugly and unnecessary.

Comment: I seem to recall that `getch`, `getc`, `fgetc` and `getchar` all return `int` values, not `char`, so you might want to change `char h;` to `int h;` and compile with `-Wall -pedantic` to be notified of any other issues

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to have one key activate your menu, and any other key move on instead of only accepting 'Y' or 'N'.  In other words, do a "Hit enter for menu any other key to continue" kind of thing.  In code this might look like:

```
printw("Hit 'H' for help, any other key to continue\n");
h = getch();
if(h == 'y' || h == 'Y') {
    printw("Helpful stuff here.\n");
}

printw("Getting on with our lives here, with or without help);
```

If you don't want the entered character to show up, you can toggle echo in ncurses with:

```
echo()    // Turns on echo of keystrokes
noecho()  // Turns off echo of keystrokes
```

Details on these functions available [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/echo).